# Loop through all controls on asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I need to loop through all the controls in my asp.net webpage and do something to the control.  In one instance I'm making a giant string out of the page and emailing it to myself, and in another case I'm saving everything to a cookie.

The problem is masterpages and items with collections of controls inside them.  I want to be able to pass in a Page to the method, then have that method be generic enough to loop through all controls in the inner-most content page and work with them.  I've tried doing this with recursion, but my recursion is incomplete.

I want to pass a Page object into a method, and have that method loop through all controls in the innermost content page.  How can I achieve this?

```
    private static String controlToString(Control control)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    String controlID = String.Empty;

    Type type = null;

    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        try
        {
            controlID = c.ID.ToString();

            if (c is IEditableTextControl)
            {
                result.Append(controlID + ": " + ((IEditableTextControl)c).Text);
                result.Append("<br />");
            }
            else if (c is ICheckBoxControl)
            {
                result.Append(controlID + ": " + ((ICheckBoxControl)c).Checked);
                result.Append("<br />");
            }
            else if (c is ListControl)
            {
                result.Append(controlID + ": " + ((ListControl)c).SelectedValue);
                result.Append("<br />");
            }
            else if (c.HasControls())
            {
                result.Append(controlToString(c));
            }

            //result.Append("<br />");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Without Try/catch

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

On line controlID = .....

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: No error, my string simply doesn't have entries representing every control.

Comment: The reason you're not getting an error is because you have a try/catch block hiding it. Remove that and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your original method will not work if you start from the root element of your document: something like page.Controls as you will only loop through the first level of controls, but remember a control can be composite. So you need recursion to pull that off.

```
        public void FindTheControls(List<Control> foundSofar, Control parent) 
        {

            foreach(var c in parent.Controls) 
            {
                  if(c is IControl) //Or whatever that is you checking for 
                  {

                      foundSofar.Add(c);

                      if(c.Controls.Count > 0) 
                      {
                            this.FindTheControls(foundSofar, c);
                      }
                  }


            }  

        }
```

Comment: Ok, so can I pass a Page object into this?  What can I pass into this?

Comment: Also, what is the advantage of using var c over Control c?

Comment: @MAW74656 Syntactic sugar, they are the same

Comment: So, if I'm looking for TextBoxes, it will check if the current control is a textbox, add it, and then check if that textbox has child controls? What if I'm looking for textboxes and the current control is a panel in which my textbox resides? This code doesn't seem to account for that.

Comment: To my understanding, textboxes, labels, checkboxes etc are not containers so a textbox cannot contain a textbox so if you are looking for text boxes, it will find them even in a child panel.

Answer (score 26):

I rather like David Finleys linq approach to FindControl http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2007/06/29/linq-the-uber-findcontrol.aspx

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> All(this ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            foreach (Control grandChild in control.Controls.All())
                yield return grandChild;

            yield return control;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// get the first empty textbox
TextBox firstEmpty = accountDetails.Controls
    .All()
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(tb => tb.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
    .FirstOrDefault();

// and focus it
if (firstEmpty != null)
    firstEmpty.Focus();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (Control ctlMaster in Page.Controls)
{
    if (ctlMaster is MasterPage)
    {
        foreach (Control ctlForm in ctlMaster.Controls)
        {
            if (ctlForm is HtmlForm)
            {
                foreach (Control ctlContent in ctlForm.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctlContent is ContentPlaceHolder)
                    {
                        foreach (Control ctlChild in ctlContent.Controls)
                        {
                            //Do something!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should do it. Though you might need to do some checking to make sure you're actually dealing with the correct ContentPlaceHolder if there's more than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub getcontrols(byref c as control, byref allControls as list(of control)
if c isnot nothing
allcontrols.add(c)
if c.controls.count>0 then
for each ctrl as control in c.controls
getcontrols(ctrl,allcontrols)
next
end if
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant to the ASP.net question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ..

Just make sure you ID all your controls starting with the prefixes shown below. ie: `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail"...>` for example. Otherwise the parser will not detect your control. If someone has a better way of parsing without knowing / hard-coding the ID of the controls, that would be even sweeter.

```
protected String GetControls(Control control)
{
    //Get text from form elements
    String text = "";
    foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.ClientID.Contains("TextBox"))
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            text += tb.ID.Replace("TextBox", "") + ": " + tb.Text + "<br />";
        }
        if (ctrl.ClientID.Contains("RadioButtonList"))
        {
            RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)ctrl;
            text += rbl.ID.Replace("RadioButtonList", "") + ": " + rbl.SelectedItem.Text + "<br />";
        }
        if (ctrl.ClientID.Contains("DropDownList"))
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ctrl;
            text += ddl.ID.Replace("DropDownList", "") + ": " + ddl.SelectedItem.Text + "<br />";
        }

        if (ctrl.ClientID.Contains("CheckBox"))
        {
            CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)ctrl;
            text += cb1.ID.Replace("CheckBox", "") + ": " + cb1.Text + "<br />";
        }

        if (ctrl.HasControls())
            text += GetControls(ctrl);
    }

    return text;
}
```

And to call it, passing Page object ...

```
String log;
foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Controls)
    log += GetControls(ctrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code. This should help you with all the controls you need. You should be able to use Web Page Controls, as well as ASP.NET Controls.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

List<Control> lstControl = new List<Control>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private List<Label> getLabels() // Add all Lables to a list
{
    List<Label> lLabels = new List<Label>();

    foreach (Control oControl in Page.Controls)
    {
        GetAllControlsInWebPage(oControl);
    }

    foreach (Control oControl in lstControl)
    {
        if (oControl.GetType() == typeof(Label))
        {
            lLabels.Add((Label)oControl);
        }
    }
    return lLabels;
}

protected void GetAllControlsInWebPage(Control oControl)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in oControl.Controls)
    {
        lstControl.Add(childControl); //lstControl - Global variable
        if (childControl.HasControls())
            GetAllControlsInWebPage(childControl);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though this question has been discussed for more than 9 years, here I leave the code that worked for me based on @Jagadheesh Venkatesan's code.

```
private List<Control> getControls()
{
    List<Control> lControls = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control oControl in Page.Controls)
        foreach (Control childControl1 in oControl.Controls)
            foreach (Control childControl2 in childControl1.Controls)
                foreach (Control childControl3 in childControl2.Controls)
                    if (childControl3.GetType().ToString().Contains("System.Web.UI.WebControls"))
                        lControls.Add(childControl3);
    return lControls;
}
```