# How to set maxlength for multiline TextBox?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

When using a MultiLine TextBox (which generates a TextArea) setting the MaxLength property has no effect. What is the best workaround? I'd like to get basic, intended functionality with minimum of ugly javascript etc. Just prevent user from entering more than max number of characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying maxlength for multiline textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334286/specifying-maxlength-for-multiline-textbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to let the user know if he exceeded the amount of characters as he writes, you could use a javascript function attached to keypress event. This function would test the length of the input and cancel the character rendering if the maxlenght was reached.

Another option is to use `RegularExpressionValidator` control to validate the input on submit.

In my opinion, the first option is much more better.

I'm not adding any code since google is full of examples for all tastes, this is a very common task.

[Here](https://www.google.com.ar/#hl=es&sclient=psy-ab&q=multiline+textbox+maxlength&oq=multiline+textbox+maxlength&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=5132l5288l0l5522l2l2l0l0l0l1l227l227l2-1l1l0&gs_l=serp.3...5132l5288l0l5522l2l2l0l0l0l1l227l227l2-1l1l0.llsin.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c452ca4d959557aa&biw=1399&bih=790) you have a sample search that might help.

Answer (score 26):

If you don't care about older browsers (see [supported browsers here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)),
you can set MaxLength normally like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="100" />
```

and force it to be printed out to the HTML

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
    txt1.Attributes.Add("maxlength", txt1.MaxLength.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cross browser solution :

```
<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ID="txtPurpose" Columns="50" Rows="2" onkeypress="return isokmaxlength(event,this,255);" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript :

```
function isokmaxlength(e,val,maxlengt) {
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode

    if (!(charCode == 44 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 0 || charCode == 8 || (val.value.length < maxlengt))) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You have to think about the Copy and Paste. This is a little bit tricky, I simply disable it with Jquery. But you can create your own function to do more complex verification. But in my case, copy and paste is not allowed.

Jquery to disable copy and paste :

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $("#txtPurpose").bind({
        paste: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a model object bind to that textbox you can use DataAnnotations attributes to  set the maxlength of that property. I'm based on MVC about that but it should work for ASP.NET too!

This way you don't mess with any Javascript or setting anything in the markup.

Comment: Unfortunately WebForms doesn't have native support of Data Annotations like MVC. But there are some workarounds, I'' check them out, Thanks! perfect example of desired answer ) +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    Dim script As String = ""

    script = script + " <script type='text/javascript'> function CheckLength(obj) {"
    script = script + "  var object = document.getElementById(obj);"
    script = script + " if (object.value.length > 5) {"
    script = script + "     object.focus();"
    script = script + "      object.value = object.value.substring(0, 5); "
    script = script + "      object.scrollTop = object.scrollHeight; "
    script = script + "      return false;"
    script = script + "   }"
    script = script + "   return true;"
    script = script + "   }</script>"


    Dim b As New TextBox()
    b.ID = "btnSomeButton"
    b.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine
    Mypanel.Controls.Add(b)
    b.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "return CheckLength('" & b.ClientID & "');")

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "key", script, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To force asp.net to send the maxlength attribute for all multiline textboxes on a page or a whole site,
building on Aximili's answer above:

1. Create a function to get all the controls on the page:

I use the control extension method from David Findley
https://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/linq-the-uber-findcontrol
and referenced in this SO post
[Loop through all controls on asp.net webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259850/loop-through-all-controls-on-asp-net-webpage#8828258)

```
namespace xyz.Extensions
{
    public static class PageExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Control> All(this ControlCollection controls)
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
            {
                foreach (Control grandChild in control.Controls.All())
                    yield return grandChild;

                yield return control;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. In the page or master page

Make sure to reference the namespace for the extension method in step 1.

Put the following code in the Page_Load function:

```
if (!IsPostBack){
    //force textareas to display maxlength attribute 
    Page.Controls.All().OfType<TextBox>().ToList()
                    .Where(x => x.TextMode == TextBoxMode.MultiLine && x.MaxLength > 0)
                    .ToList().ForEach(t => t.Attributes.Add("maxlength", t.MaxLength.ToString()));
            }
```