# Hide/show HTML divs via the class tags in ASP rather than via the ID tag

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Hopefully this will be a quick one.  I see in the following post:

[How to hide a div from code (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297165/how-to-hide-a-div-from-code-c)

Shows how to reference an ID and assign the visible property, but is there a way to do this by referencing a class tag?  I assume you would need to do it via a loop of some sort, but not sure how to do that.

I'd like to be able to set a "visibleIfLoggedIn" class and hide any divs etc that have that class assigned based on a session variable.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You could hide it with CSS. But the controls will still exist on the page client side.

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a way to loop through the elements of a certain type such as div, or all elements, and then look for class tags?

Comment: Yes, you can loop all the controls on a Page or in another Control, check the CssClass property and set the Visibility. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259850/loop-through-all-controls-on-asp-net-webpage

Comment: You can do it with vanilla JavaScript but you should probably look into jQuery. A jQuery selector can specify a class name.